# Developed report with ReportViewer 11 in visual studio 2013. Try to test in Windows 2012 R2; version 11 not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer, windows-server-2012-r2

I have developed a report in visual studio 2013 and try to test in Windows server 2012 for deployment. On running the application, it reveals that ReportViewer 11 is not found. Tried few solutions from internet, but failed to solve the issue.
My doubt is: 
1. VS2013 gave ReportViewer 11; but it seems not much people uses either VS2013 or ReportViewer 11. Is VS2013 unstable or ReportViewer 10 or 12 is the standard?
2. Is there any solutions I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description you have provided, try downloading the [Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=35747)

There is no issue with VS2013 or ReportViewer 11, it just we needed to add the runtime for specific component (in the current case it turned out to be ReportViewer).

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hello Noman, I tried installing this. But in the server, when deployed the application, the status is same. So I recreated a virtual server and installed visual studio 2013, sql server 2014 and deployed the application again. There it is working without any problem. Also, the clients can access the report. So th problem is with the Sql server 2012 in my old server? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I didn't come across issue between Report server and Sql server. However, I would like to give a try and see if it happens. Will let you know.